# AllJoyn or Wifi Direct for P2P?

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi, wifi-direct, alljoyn

For Wifi P2P in Android, and considering: time, required experience, and performance. Should I go to 3rd party frameworks like AllJoyn or just use Android Wifi Direct?

The app is not for commercial use.

Comment: Alljoyn is a framework which uses bluetooth/Wi-Fi/Wfd for transport mechanism ...alljoyn is not restricted to only wi-fi direct.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that Alljoyn employs not only Wi-Fi Direct, but Bluetooth and regular Wi-Fi, I would reccommend it's use as Wi-Fi direct is still very much in it's infancy and based on the volume of unanswered Stackoverflow questions, you are likely to run into some difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences with WiFi Direct are much like those with using Bluetooth. It's wonderful when it works smoothly, but failure to reliably connect is very common.